# WLAN on OpenWRT router

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, wireless-router, openwrt

I've installed OpenWrt Snapshot R43972 on a router that is not officially supported (a Swisscom Centro Grande resp. Pirelli / ADB according to the descriptions [here](http://bitbull.ch/wiki/index.php/Install_OpenWRT_BARRIER_BREAKER_on_Swisscom_Centro_Grande_Router) and [here](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/adb/p.dg_av4202n). However, the PCB layout is slightly different than in the photos there.

So far it seems to work, except for the wireless. I have tried most settings in LuCI, and several manual changes to `/etc/config/wireless`, but I could neither set it up as an AP nor receive any signals. Hence, I suspect that the problem is somewhere deeper, and I don't see a way to localize the problem further.

It starts nicely with

```
$> dmesg | grep b43
Sun Jan 18 23:13:32 2015 kern.info kernel: [   16.196000] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4322 WLAN found (core revision 16)
Sun Jan 18 23:13:32 2015 kern.info kernel: [   16.236000] b43-phy0: Found PHY: Analog 8, Type 4 (N), Revision 4
Sun Jan 18 23:13:32 2015 kern.info kernel: [   16.240000] b43-phy0: Found Radio: Manuf 0x17F, ID 0x2056, Revision 3, Version 0
```

But then:

```
$> logread | grep radio
Sun Jan 18 23:13:48 2015 daemon.notice netifd: radio0 (692): Configuration file: /var/run/hostapd-phy0.conf
Sun Jan 18 23:13:48 2015 daemon.notice netifd: radio0 (692): nl80211 driver initialization failed.
Sun Jan 18 23:13:48 2015 daemon.notice netifd: radio0 (692): hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0-1 wasn't started
Sun Jan 18 23:13:48 2015 daemon.notice netifd: radio0 (692): hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
Sun Jan 18 23:13:48 2015 daemon.notice netifd: radio0 (692): cat: can't open '/var/run/wifi-phy0.pid': No such file or directory
Sun Jan 18 23:13:49 2015 daemon.notice netifd: radio0 (692): Command failed: Invalid argument
Sun Jan 18 23:13:49 2015 daemon.notice netifd: radio0 (692): Device setup failed: HOSTAPD_START_FAILED
```

I would appreciate any hint on how to proceed!

*Disclaimer: I haven't gotten a reply to [this question](https://forum.openwrt.org/search.php?action=show_user_posts&user_id=138474) on the OpenWrt forums after several days, so I'm cross-posting here.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same problem on a Tenda W300D with r44093 and found the MAC address had been pre-configured wrong, so I:

1. Changed `/sys/class/ieee80211/phy0/macaddress`:

   ```bash
   # From:
     00:00:00:00:00:00

   # To the MAC on the bottom of the router:
     c8:3a:52:75:51:08
   ```
2. Changed `/var/run/hostapd-phy0.conf` to:

   ```bash
   bssid=c8:3a:52:75:51:08
   ```
3. Added to `/etc/config/wireless`:

   ```bash
   option macaddr C6:3A:35:27:51:08
   ```
4. Reset the network:

   ```bash
   /etc/init.d/network restart ; wifi up
   ```

Now the Wi-Fi should have the correct MAC set.

Comment: Amazing, I would not have thought of that!

Comment: super, how did you find this error?